# Spark SQL , doesn´t respect the Dataframe format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I m analyzing Twitter Files with the scope to take the trending topic, in json format with Spark SQL

After to take all the text form a Tweet and split the words, my dataFrame look like this

```
 +--------------------+--------------------+
 |                line|               words|
 +--------------------+--------------------+
 |[RT, @ONLYRPE:, #...|                  RT|
 |[RT, @ONLYRPE:, #...|           @ONLYRPE:|
 |[RT, @ONLYRPE:, #...|               #tlrp|
 |[RT, @ONLYRPE:, #...|           followan?|
```

I just need the column words, I coconvert my table to a temView.

```
 df.createOrReplaceTempView("Twitter_test_2")
```

With the help of spark sql should be very easy to take the trending topic, I just need a query in sql using in the where condition operator "Like". words like "#%"

```
 spark.sql("select words, 
                   count(words) as count 
            from words_Twitter 
            where words like '#%'  
            group by words 
            order by count desc limit 10").show(20,False)
```

but I m getting some strange results that  I can't find an explanation for them.

```
+---------------------+---+
|words                |cnt|
+---------------------+---+
|#izmirescort         |211|
|#PRODUCE101          |101|
|#VeranoMTV2017       |91 |
|#سلمان_يدق_خشم_العايل|89 |
|#ALDUBHomeAgain      |67 |
|#BTS                 |32 |
|#سود_الله_وجهك_ياتميم|32 |
|#NowPlaying          |32 |
```

for some reason the #89 and the #32 the twoo thar have arab characteres are no where they should been. The text had been exchanged with the counter.

others times I am confrontig tha kind of format.

```
 spark.sql("select words, lang,count(words) count from Twitter_test_2 group by words,lang order by count desc limit 10  ").show()
```

After that Query to my dataframe, it look like so strange

```
   +--------------------+----+-----+
   |               words|lang|count|
   +--------------------+----+-----+
   |      #VeranoMTV2017|  pl|    6|
   |              #umRei|  pt|    2|
   |             #Virgem|  pt|    2|
   |               #rt
   2|  pl|    2|
   |        #rt
   gazowaną|  pl|    1|
   |             #Ziobro|  pl|    1|
   |         #SomosPorto|  pt|    1|
   +--------------------+----+-----+
```

Why is happening that, and how can avoid it  ?

Comment: Arabic writing is right-to-left. So you're seeing the hash character at the "start" of their words, even if it looks like the ending for us.

Comment: Hi @Dai thank you very much for your Answer,  I never would  have fallen  for that.  So you mean that te result is correct ?  there is a way to avoid that ? that its look like all character look like left to right